# Strange Failure issue in Protractor:Jasmine test cases?

Tags: angular, selenium, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

**UPDATED THE QUESTION ON 17th Sep 2018 Update in Emphasised text**

When my test case passes I have no issues in the output screen. It says passed. But when it fails I get this long red output which I am pretty sure is not just about the failure something is wrong in the setup. I am learning automation. Advise me on this. Sharing Info below.

What does this error message imply from the code. Thanks

app.po.ts

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
  export class TestEngine {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/');
  }

  getParagraphText() {
    return expect(element(by.tagName('p')).getText())
  }
}
```

testspec.ts

```
import { TestEngine } from './app.po';

describe('My Test Engine App', () => {
  let page: TestEngine;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new TestEngine();
  });

  it('should display display MyTestEngine', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect (page.getParagraphText()).toBeFalsy();

    });
});
```

***EDIT-1 Updating Error message: As you can see here the test cases are passed but I get these errors still at initial stage yet they run . I am working behind a proxy . Is it having something to do with it?***

```
[14:50:39] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[14:50:39] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[15964:14512:0917/145041.292:ERROR:install_util.cc(629)] Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58624/devtools/browser/7afe23b7-6bcb-4221-8f77-6adf646b3bd0
[15964:14512:0917/145043.057:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
Jasmine started
(node:4300) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[15964:9956:0917/145046.586:ERROR:platform_sensor_provider_win.cc(45)] Unable to create instance of SensorManager: Class not registered (0x80040154)

  My Test Engine App
    √ should display display My Test Engine

Executed 1 of 1 spec SUCCESS in 10 secs.
[14:50:55] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[14:50:55] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

Error-1

```
protractor
[17:27:23] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[17:27:23] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[12416:892:0914/172724.857:ERROR:install_util.cc(629)] Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52345/devtools/browser/7fa56311-7a3d-4e7e-8ce7-f96abcf783c8
[12416:892:0914/172726.326:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
Jasmine started
(node:7232) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[12416:15788:0914/172730.408:ERROR:platform_sensor_provider_win.cc(45)] Unable to create instance of SensorManager: Class not registered (0x80040154)
[17:27:44] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, p) - the first result will be used
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

  My Test Engine App
    × should display display My Test Engine
      - Expected Expectation({ util: Object({ equals: Function, contains: Function, buildFailureMessage: Function }), customEqualityTesters: [  ], actual: ElementFinder({ browser_: ProtractorBrowser({ controlFlow: Function, schedule: Function, setFileDetector: Function, getExecutor: Function, getSession: Function, getCapabilities: Function, quit: Function, actions: Function, touchActions: Function, executeScript: Function, executeAsyncScript: Function, call: Function, wait: Function, sleep: Function, getWindowHandle: Function, getAllWindowHandles: Function, getPageSource: Function, close: Function, getCurrentUrl: Function, getTitle: Function, findElementInternal_: Function, findElementsInternal_: Function, takeScreenshot: Function, manage: Function, switchTo: Function, driver: Driver({ flow_: ControlFlow::155
      | TaskQueue::110
      | | (pending) Task::109<Run it("should display display MyEngine") in control flow>
      | | | (active) TaskQueue::113
      | | | | Task::116<<anonymous>>
      | | | | Task::118<then>
      | | | | Task::120<then>
      | | | | Task::122<then>
      | | | | Task::124<then>
      | | | | Task::126<then>
      | | | | Task::128<then>
      | | | | Task::130<then>
      | | | | Task::132<then>
      | | | | Task::134<then>
      | | | | Task::136<then>
      | | | | Task::138<Set angular root selector to null>
      | | | | Task::140<then>
      | | | | Task::142<then>
      | | | | Task::144<then>
      | | | | Task::146<then>
      | | | | Task::148<then>
      | | | | Task::150<then>
      | | | | Task::152<then>
      | | | | Task::154<then>
      | | Task::112<then>, session_: ManagedPromise::4 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"}, executor_: Executor({ w3c: false, customCommands_: Map( [ 'launchApp', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/launch_app' }) ], [ 'getNetworkConditions', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/network_conditions' }) ], [ 'setNetworkConditions', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/network_conditions' }) ], [ 'getNetworkConnection', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/network_connection' }) ], [ 'setNetworkConnection', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/network_connection' }) ], [ 'toggleAirplaneMode', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/toggle_airplane_mode' }) ], [ 'toggleWiFi', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/toggle_wifi' }) ], [ 'toggleData', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/toggle_data' }) ], [ 'toggleLocationServices', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/toggle_location_services' }) ], [ 'getGeolocation', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/location' }) ], [ 'setGeolocation', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/location' }) ], [ 'getCurrentDeviceActivity', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/current_activity' }) ], [ 'startDeviceActivity', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/start_activity' }) ], [ 'getAppiumSettings', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/settings' }) ], [ 'setAppiumSettings', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/settings' }) ], [ 'getCurrentContext', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/context' }) ], [ 'selectContext', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/context' }) ], [ 'getScreenOrientation', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/orientation' }) ], [ 'setScreenOrientation', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/orientation' }) ], [ 'isDeviceLocked', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/is_locked' }) ], [ 'lockDevice', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/lock' }) ], [ 'unlockDevice', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/unlock' }) ], [ 'installApp', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/install_app' }) ], [ 'isAppInstalled', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/app_installed' }) ], [ 'removeApp', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/remove_app' }) ], [ 'pullFileFromDevice', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/pull_file' }) ], [ 'pullFolderFromDevice', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/pull_folder' }) ], [ 'pushFileToDevice', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/push_file' }) ], [ 'listContexts', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/contexts' }) ], [ 'uploadFile', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/file' }) ], [ 'switchToParentFrame', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/frame/parent' }) ], [ 'fullscreen', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/window/fullscreen' }) ], [ 'sendAppToBackground', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/app/background' }) ], [ 'closeApp', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/app/close' }) ], [ 'getAppStrings', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/app/strings' }) ], [ 'launchSession', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/app/launch' }) ], [ 'resetApp', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/app/reset' }) ], [ 'hideSoftKeyboard', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/hide_keyboard' }) ], [ 'getDeviceTime', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/system_time' }) ], [ 'openDeviceNotifications', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/open_notifications' }) ], [ 'rotationGesture', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/rotate' }) ], [ 'shakeDevice', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/shake' }) ], [ 'sendChromiumCommand', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/send_command' }) ], [ 'sendChromiumCommandAndGetResult', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/send_command_and_get_result' }) ] ), log_: Logger({ name_: 'webdriver.http.Executor', level_: null, parent_: Logger({ name_: 'webdriver.http', level_: null, parent_: Logger({ name_: 'webdriver', level_: null, parent_: Logger({ name_: '', level_: OFF, parent_: null, handlers_: null }), handlers_: null }), handlers_: null }), handlers_: null }) }), fileDetector_: null, onQuit_: undefined, getNetworkConnection: Function, setNetworkConnection: Function, toggleAirplaneMode: Function, toggleWiFi: Function, toggleData: Function, toggleLocationServices: Function, getGeolocation: Function, setGeolocation: Function, getCurrentDeviceActivity: Function, startDeviceActivity: Function, getAppiumSettings: Function, setAppiumSettings: Function, getCurrentContext: Function, selectContext: Function, getScreenOrientation: Function, setScreenOrientation: Function, isDeviceLocked: Function, lockDevice: Function, unlockDevice: Function, installApp: Function, isAppInstalled: Function, removeApp: Function, pullFileFromDevice: Function, pullFolderFromDevice: Function, pushFileToDevice: Function, listContexts: Function, uploadFile: Function, switchToParentFrame: Function, fullscreen: Function, sendAppToBackground: Function, closeApp: Function, getAppStrings: Function, launchSession: Function, resetApp: Function, hideSoftKeyboard: Function, getDeviceTime: Function, openDeviceNotifications: Function, rotationGesture: Function, shakeDevice: Function, sendChromiumCommand: Function, sendChromiumCommandAndGetResult: Function }), element: Function, $: Function, $$: Function, baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100/', getPageTimeout: 10000, params: Object({  }), resetUrl: 'data:text/html,<html></html>', debugHelper: DebugHelper({ browserUnderDebug_: <circular reference: Object> }), ready: ManagedPromise::17 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"}, trackOutstandingTimeouts_: true, mockModules_: [ Object({ name: 'protractorBaseModule_', script: Function, args: [ true ] }) ], ExpectedConditions: ProtractorExpectedConditions({ browser: <circular reference: Object> }), plugins_: Plugins({ setup: Function, onPrepare: Function, teardown: Function, postResults: Function, postTest: Function, onPageLoad: Function, onPageStable: Function, waitForPromise: Function, waitForCondition: Function, pluginObjs: [  ], assertions: Object({  }), resultsReported: false }), allScriptsTimeout: 11000, getProcessedConfig: Function, forkNewDriverInstance: Function, restart: Function, restartSync: Function, internalRootEl: '', internalIgnoreSynchronization: false }), then: Function, parentElementArrayFinder: ElementArrayFinder({ browser_: ProtractorBrowser({ controlFlow: Function, schedule: Function, setFileDetector: Function, getExecutor: Function, getSession: Function, getCapabilities: Function, quit: Function, actions: Function, touchActions: Function, executeScript: Function, executeAsyncScript: Function, call: Function, wait: Function, sleep: Function, getWindowHandle: Function, getAllWindowHandles: Function, getPageSource: Function, close: Function, getCurrentUrl: Function, getTitle: Function, findElementInternal_: Function, findElementsInternal_: Function, takeScreenshot: Function, manage: Function, switchTo: Function, driver: Driver({ flow_: ControlFlow::155
      | TaskQueue::110
      | | (pending) Task::109<Run it("should display display MyEngine") in control flow>
      | | | (active) TaskQueue::113
      | | | | Task::116<<anonymous>>
      | | | | Task::118<then>
      | | | | Task::120<then>
      | | | | Task::122<then>
      | | | | Task::124<then>
      | | | | Task::126<then>
      | | | | Task::128<then>
      | | | | Task::130<then>
      | | | | Task::132<then>
      | | | | Task::134<then>
      | | | | Task::136<then>
      | | | | Task::138<Set angular root selector to null>
      | | | | Task::140<then>
      | | | | Task::142<then>
      | | | | Task::144<then>
      | | | | Task::146<then>
      | | | | Task::148<then>
      | | | | Task::150<then>
      | | | | Task::152<then>
      | | | | Task::154<then>
      | | Task::112<then>, session_: ManagedPromise::4 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"}, executor_: Executor({ w3c: false, customCommands_: Map( [ 'launchApp', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/launch_app' }) ], [ 'getNetworkConditions', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/network_conditions' }) ], [ 'setNetworkConditions', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/network_conditions' }) ], [ 'getNetworkConnection', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/network_connection' }) ], [ 'setNetworkConnection', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/network_connection' }) ], [ 'toggleAirplaneMode', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/toggle_airplane_mode' }) ], [ 'toggleWiFi', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/toggle_wifi' }) ], [ 'toggleData', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/toggle_data' }) ], [ 'toggleLocationServices', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/toggle_location_services' }) ], [ 'getGeolocation', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/location' }) ], [ 'setGeolocation', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/location' }) ], [ 'getCurrentDeviceActivity', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/current_activity' }) ], [ 'startDeviceActivity', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/start_activity' }) ], [ 'getAppiumSettings', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/settings' }) ], [ 'setAppiumSettings', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/settings' }) ], [ 'getCurrentContext', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/context' }) ], [ 'selectContext', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/context' }) ], [ 'getScreenOrientation', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/orientation' }) ], [ 'setScreenOrientation', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/orientation' }) ], [ 'isDeviceLocked', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/is_locked' }) ], [ 'lockDevice', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/lock' }) ], [ 'unlockDevice', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/unlock' }) ], [ 'installApp', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/install_app' }) ], [ 'isAppInstalled', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/app_installed' }) ], [ 'removeApp', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/remove_app' }) ], [ 'pullFileFromDevice', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/pull_file' }) ], [ 'pullFolderFromDevice', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/pull_folder' }) ], [ 'pushFileToDevice', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/push_file' }) ], [ 'listContexts', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/contexts' }) ], [ 'uploadFile', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/file' }) ], [ 'switchToParentFrame', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/frame/parent' }) ], [ 'fullscreen', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/window/fullscreen' }) ], [ 'sendAppToBackground', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/app/background' }) ], [ 'closeApp', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/app/close' }) ], [ 'getAppStrings', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/app/strings' }) ], [ 'launchSession', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/app/launch' }) ], [ 'resetApp', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/app/reset' }) ], [ 'hideSoftKeyboard', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/hide_keyboard' }) ], [ 'getDeviceTime', Object({ method: 'GET', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/system_time' }) ], [ 'openDeviceNotifications', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/open_notifications' }) ], [ 'rotationGesture', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/rotate' }) ], [ 'shakeDevice', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/appium/device/shake' }) ], [ 'sendChromiumCommand', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/send_command' }) ], [ 'sendChromiumCommandAndGetResult', Object({ method: 'POST', path: '/session/:sessionId/chromium/send_command_and_get_result' }) ] ), log_: Logger({ name_: 'webdriver.http.Executor', level_: null, parent_: Logger({ name_: 'webdriver.http', level_: null, parent_: Logger({ name_: 'webdriver', level_: null, parent_: Logger({ name_: '', level_: OFF, parent_: null, handlers_: null }), handlers_: null }), handlers_: null }), handlers_: null }) }), fileDetector_: null, onQuit_: undefined, getNetworkConnection: Function, setNetworkConnection: Function, toggleAirplaneMode: Function, toggleWiFi: Function, toggleData: Function, toggleLocationServices: Function, getGeolocation: Function, setGeolocation: Function, getCurrentDeviceActivity: Function, startDeviceActivity: Function, getAppiumSettings: Function, setAppiumSettings: Function, getCurrentContext: Function, selectContext: Function, getScreenOrientation: Function, setScreenOrientation: Function, isDeviceLocked: Function, lockDevice: Function, unlockDevice: Function, installApp: Function, isAppInstalled: Function, removeApp: Function, pullFileFromDevice: Function, pullFolderFromDevice: Function, pushFileToDevice: Function, listContexts: Function, uploadFile: Function, switchToParentFrame: Function, fullscreen: Function, sendAppToBackground: Function, closeApp: Function, getAppStrings: Function, launchSession: Function, resetApp: Function, hideSoftKeyboard: Function, getDeviceTime: Function, openDeviceNotifications: Function, rotationGesture: Function, shakeDevice: Function, sendChromiumCommand: Function, sendChromiumCommandAndGetResult: Function }), element: Function, $: Function, $$: Function, baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100/', getPageTimeout: 10000, params: Object({  }), resetUrl: 'data:text/html,<html></html>', debugHelper: DebugHelper({ browserUnderDebug_: <circular reference: Object> }), ready: ManagedPromise::17 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"}, trackOutstandingTimeouts_: true, mockModules_: [ Object({ name: 'protractorBaseModule_', script: Function, args: [ true ] }) ], ExpectedConditions: ProtractorExpectedConditions({ browser: <circular reference: Object> }), plugins_: Plugins({ setup: Function, onPrepare: Function, teardown: Function, postResults: Function, postTest: Function, onPageLoad: Function, onPageStable: Function, waitForPromise: Function, waitForCondition: Function, pluginObjs: [  ], assertions: Object({  }), resultsReported: false }), allScriptsTimeout: 11000, getProcessedConfig: Function, forkNewDriverInstance: Function, restart: Function, restartSync: Function, internalRootEl: '', internalIgnoreSynchronization: false }), getWebElements: Function, locator_: By(css selector, p), actionResults_: ManagedPromise::153 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}, click: Function, sendKeys: Function, getTagName: Function, getCssValue: Function, getAttribute: Function, getText: Function, getSize: Function, getLocation: Function, isEnabled: Function, isSelected: Function, submit: Function, clear: Function, isDisplayed: Function, getId: Function, takeScreenshot: Function }), elementArrayFinder_: ElementArrayFinder({ browser_: ProtractorBrowser({ controlFlow: Function, schedule: Function, setFileDetector: Function, getExecutor: Function, getSession: Function, getCapabilities: Function, quit: Function, actions: Function, touchActions: Function, executeScript: Function, executeAsyncScript: Function, call: Function, wait: Function, sleep: Function, getWindowHandle: Function, getAllWindowHandles: Function, getPageSource: Function, close: Function, getCurrentUrl: Function, getTitle: Function, findElementInternal_: Function, findElementsInternal_: Function, takeScreenshot: Function, manage: Function, switchTo: Function, driver: Driver({ flow_: ControlFlow::155
```

Comment: Can anyone explain the error message which I have updated in the question. What does those error messages imply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long error occurs in an erroneous `expect(...)`.

You're trying to do this:

```
it('should display display MyEngine', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(expect(element(by.tagName('p')).getText())).toBeFalsy(); 
    // It looks strange because the method getParagraphText does not
    // return a string, it returns an "expect call"
});
```

To fix your error you should only return the text of the paragraph:

```
getParagraphText() {
    return element(by.tagName('p')).getText();
}

it('should display display MyEngine', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('Want to validate an engine?'); 
});
```

The return type of `getParagraphText` is `Promise<string>`. So you're expecting that `Promise<string>` is equal to your `string` 'Want to validate an engine?'.

As workaround you can do something like this:

```
page.getParagraphText().then((text) => {
    expect(text).toEqual('Want to validate an engine?');
});
```

Comment: .It worked! .As you have mentioned I have expected a expect call instead of a string. Now issue is solved. Cheers!

Comment: @yong @Batajus . After making modifications in the code when I add a line 

`expect (page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('Want to validate an engine?');`
``

I get an error on VS code when I hover over the redline(error) it displays a pop up which says
`[ts] Argument of type "Want to validate an engine?" is not as signable to parameter of type 'Expected<Promise<string>>'.`

But it runs in cmd manager and passes or fails accordingly but I am still curious about what this error message says. Could you guys help me out

Comment: execute  `npm install --save @types/jasmine  @types/jasminewd2`

Comment: @yong didnt fix . Those error message still stays . and also could you kindly clarify what this error statement states `[ts] Argument of type "Want to validate an engine?" is not as signable to parameter of type 'Expected<Promise<string>>`

Comment: @batajus , @yong appreciate your efforts. The workaround fixed the VSCode error and also thanks @batajus for explaining the error in clear terms. Now there is only one thing which is bugging me still those errors splitting them in consecutive comments `[15:46:23] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:46:23] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[6448:13852:0918/154625.290:ERROR:install_util.cc(629)] Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)`

Comment: `DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49522/devtools/browser/76faf9ba-a0c1-47cc-850c-bd4a326154df
[6448:13852:0918/154626.858:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
Jasmine started
(node:5764) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[6448:10368:0918/154629.579:ERROR:platform_sensor_provider_win.cc(45)] Unable to create instance of SensorManager: Class not registered (0x80040154)`

Comment: Even if i cant find a solution to these errors. I would like to know why they occur ?